# Want to create Virtual machine on azure with Microsoft default images and sizes in C# application using Azure API

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Want to create Virtual machine on azure with Microsoft default images and sizes in C# application using Azure API.

[image]

Like while we have Image and Size option here (as in image)

Please guide how can I acheive the same.

Comment: do you mean how to create a virtual machine using the Azure CLI?http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/

Comment: Or using Service Management API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157194.aspx.

Comment: I want to use default images as in screenshot. Which Microsoft uses when we create a VM on azure. like windows 2012 system center R2, window 2012 system center.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest option is to either go after the [Azure Management REST API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx), or to take a look at the [open source Azure Powershell Cmdlets](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools) (which use C# & the REST API under the covers).

Comment: Thanks. I have gone through the Azure Management REST API documentation and my query is not explained there.

Comment: Presuming you've already created the cloud service into which the vm will be placed, you'll need to call the Add Role API call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547424/want-to-create-virtual-machine-on-azure-with-microsoft-default-images-and-sizes/25549700?noredirect=1#comment40075568_25549700. I believe that to specify the Image and Size look at the request body schema nodes VMImageName and RoleSize.

Comment: Hi Brent. Thanks a lot for replying for my queries. Yes, I have already created the cloud service. And I can also create the VMs using my images (VM images created by my) and any VM sizes but I want to know - can I create the VMs using the default images provided by microsoft as in my screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

To find a specific image you can make the '[List OS Images](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157191.aspx)' Rest call.

If you make an authenticated call to

> https://management.core.windows.net//services/images

Then you will get a response that contains all of the images available to your subscription. This is a very large list that you will then need to parse to find the specific image that you require.